# Error Building Dlib Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, dlib

I have been trying to compile dlib library in visual studio.

1. So I created an empty project.
2. I added face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp and source.cpp from dlib/all folder into my project (I copied paste the aforementioned into "Source Files" in my project).
3. I added: C:\Users\user\Desktop\dlib2\dlib-19.4 and C:\Users\user\Desktop\dlib2\dlib-19.4\dlib\external\libjpeg and C:\Users\user\Desktop\dlib2\dlib-19.4\dlib\external\libpng into the include directory.
4. And added DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT and DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT into the C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Defintion.
5. the platform chosen is Active(win32).
6. Under Debugging -> Command Argument, I added the following arguments: C:\Users\user\Desktop\dlib2\dlib-19.4\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat C:\Users\user\Desktop\dlib2\dlib-19.4\examples\faces*.jpg

When trying to build the project I got the following errors: 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _png_set_sig_bytes referenced in function "private: void __thiscall dlib::png_loader::read_image(char const *)" (?read_image@png_loader@dlib@@AAEXPBD@Z) dlibTest    c:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\dlibTest\dlibTest\source.obj    1

*Any help is much appreciated!!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the source files from the libpng and libjpeg folders too.